# Do we have to implement all the methods and properties of a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I just want to ask you in Objective-C if we conform to a protocol in our class do we have to implement all the methods declared in the protocol?

```
@interface MyClass:NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
{

}
@end
```

in this example do I have to implement all the methods inside NSCopying and NSCoding protocols?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by _not_ implementing the methods?

Comment: What would be the point of adopting a protocol if it had no implications for the implementation? As a practical matter, how would you expect instance of `MyClass` to be copied if you didn't implement copying when adopting `NSCopying`? And similarly for coding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement all the methods that are marked `@required`, yes.  That is the whole point of a protocol;  it defines a set of optional and required methods that must be implemented to conform to the protocol.

If the superclass implements the protocol, then you'll inherit that implementation, but it is unlikely to be sufficient for either `NSCopying` or `NSCoding`.  Thus, you'll override the methods (and call `super`'s implementation in yours).